# Normalization Technique for Feature Level Fusion

Tags: normalization, biometrics

I am currently working on Feature Level Fusion of Face and Fingerprint Modalities.
I have used Gabor wavelet (at 8 orientations and 5 scales) to extract features. Later I have used PCA and LDA.
Which technique should be used to normalize feature vectors (as they are from heterogeneous sources) for feature level fusion?
When should the normalization be applied  before fusion (simple concatenation) of feature vectors or after fusion of feature vectors?